# How do I solve the following limit with L'Hospital?

Tags: limits

How can I solve $\lim_{x->0}\frac{(x-sinx)^2}{(e^{x^2}-1)x^4}$? I wrote it like this $\lim_{x->0}\frac{(x-sinx)^2*x^2}{(e^{x^2}-1)x^6}$ and $\lim_{x->0}\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}-1}=1$ and after I used L'Hospital but I get $\frac{1}{0}$. I think that I do something wrong.

Comment: Best thing is to share with us what you did...we can perhaps find the mistake

Comment: I did already. I told you that I used L'Hospital to calculate the limit.

Comment: How did you apply L'Hospital's rule?  To what did you apply it?

Comment: You might do better multiplying top and bottom by $x^{-6}$ rather than by $x^2$

Comment: I applied to $\lim_{x->0}\frac{(x-sinx)^2}{x^6}$

Comment: @Henry you should get the same result.

Comment: I think $\sin x = x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^4)$

Comment: Do you have to do the limit with Hospital's Rule? On your limit you would have to apply three times before getting an answer. Too much time to type up. The answer with series, as provided is much quicker...

Comment: I know it might be easier but I should use L'Hospital. That's what the exercise says.

Answer (score 2):

**Mixed method**:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}-1}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac t{e^t-1}=1.$$
Then
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x-\sin x)^2}{x^6}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\right)^2.$$

By L'Hospital, twice

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{6x}=\frac16.$$

Hence

$$\frac1{36}.$$

---

**The hard way**:

At the sixth application of L'Hospital,

$$\frac{2x\sin(x)+32\cos^2(x)-32\sin^2(x)-12\cos(x)}{64x^{10}e^{x^2}+1248x^8e^{x^2}+7440x^6e^{x^2}+15480x^4e^{x^2}+9360x^2e^{x^2}+720e^{x^2}}\to\frac{20}{720}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}-1}
$$ 
is an indeterminate form as $0^2$ is $0$, and $e^0=1$, so the numerator and denominator are both zero.  Therefore, we may apply l'Hopital's rule to get that this limit equals
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2x}{2xe^{x^2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}.
$$ 
Since $e^0=1$, plugging in $0$ for $x$ gives that this limit is $1$.

For
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x-\sin(x))^2}{x^6},
$$
we notice that this is a square, and we can compute
$$
\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}\right)^2
$$
We can calculate 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}
$$
Since $x$ and $\sin(x)$ are zero when we substitute for $x$, this is an indeterminate form and we can apply l'Hopital's rule to get 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{3x^2}
$$
Since $\cos(0)=1$, we again have the indeterminate form where the numerator and denominator are zero, so we apply l'Hopital's rule again to get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{6x}.
$$
We can apply l'Hopital's rule one more time or observe that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ (this comes from a standard squeeze theorem application), so this limit comes out to $\frac{1}{6}$.

Combining everything, the limit is $\frac{1}{36}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\sin (x)=x-\frac {x^3}{6}(1+\epsilon_1 (x)) $$

and

$$e^{x^2}=1+x^2 (1+\epsilon_2 (x)) $$

your limit is

$$\frac {1}{36} $$

in this case,  Taylor is simpler.

Comment: I should solve it with L'Hospital not because you can not with Taylor but I know that you can do it with L'Hospital too.